# sweetalert.js not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to use sweetalert.js in my laravel app and I'm using it for delete buttons, the problem is whether i use `OK` button or `CANCEL` button it delete my data.

## Code

`Button`

I'm adding `'onsubmit' => 'return ConfirmDelete()'` in my form.

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['attribute-groups.destroy', $attribute->id],'onsubmit' => 'return ConfirmDelete()' ]) !!}
  <button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm" type="submit"><span class="fas fa-times"></span></button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

`JavaScript`

```
<script>
function ConfirmDelete(){
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this group or it's values!",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
      if (willDelete) {
        swal("Poof! Your group file has been deleted!", {
          icon: "success",
        });
      } else {
        swal("Your group file is safe!");
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

**PS:**

If I use something simple like

```
<script>
  function ConfirmDelete(){
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
  }
</script>
```

`OK` and `CANCEL` buttons work perfectly but seems like sweet alert needs more work to do that.

**Any idea?**

## Update

based on `Mozammil` here is what i have now:

`delete form`

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['attribute-groups.destroy', $attribute->id]]) !!}
  <button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Delete" class="del btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm" type="submit"><span class="fas fa-times"></span></button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

`js`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.del').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this group or it's values!",
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true,
            })
            .then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).closest('form').attr('action'),
                        type: 'DELETE',
                        success: function(result) {
                            swal("Poof! Your group file has been deleted!", {
                                icon: "success",
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    swal("Your group file is safe!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Issue**

Now `CANCEL` button will cancel activity, and `OK` button behave as cancel button too.

Both do cancel.

[image: one]

## Update 2

`controller function`

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $attribute = AttributeGroup::findOrFail($id);
        $values = Attribute::where('attribute_id',$attribute->id)->get();
        foreach($values as $value){
            $value->delete();
        }
        $attribute->delete();
        Session::flash('success', 'Attribute Group Deleted Successfully.');
        return redirect()->route('attribute-groups.index');
    }
```

PS: I am getting `419` error in my network tab when i click ok, i added

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
});
```

yet i'm getting same error `419`

Comment: Seems like you got it right from the documentation. Could you `console.log(willDelete)`?

Comment: @Mozammil it says true

Comment: @Mozammil on cancel will not print anything but yet it deletes my data

Comment: Well, it makes sense. You are adding it on `onSubmit()`. The form reloads the page and sweetalert won't print anything. The only way to do what you want is if you perform your delete action in the callback.

Comment: @Mozammil how to?

Comment: You will add an `onClick` listener to the delete button that would pop up the sweet alert and on confirmation submit a delete request.

Comment: @Mozammil i changed my code to `'onClick' => 'return ConfirmDelete()'` still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simplistic example of how you could get this to work.

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this group or it's values!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('attribute-groups.destroy', ['id' => $attribute->id]) }}",
                type: 'DELETE',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    // reloads the page..
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        } else {
            swal("Your group file is safe!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186467/discussion-on-answer-by-mozammil-sweetalert-js-not-behaving-properly).